# Class constructor ObjectId cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to use `get` method in express from a local mongodb database, for a request `/Movies/:id`, it should extract the details of the movie. But instead it is throwing me a error below

```
TypeError: Class constructor ObjectId cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at /home/srithan/Desktop/Right_doc/Tutorial/mongodb/Mongo/app.js:59:24
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/srithan/Desktop/Right_doc/Tutorial/mongodb/Mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/srithan/Desktop/Right_doc/Tutorial/mongodb/Mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/srithan/Desktop/Right_doc/Tutorial/mongodb/Mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/srithan/Desktop/Right_doc/Tutorial/mongodb/Mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/srithan/Desktop/Right_doc/Tutorial/mongodb/Mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
    at param (/home/srithan/Desktop/Right_doc/Tutorial/mongodb/Mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at param (/home/srithan/Desktop/Right_doc/Tutorial/mongodb/Mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:376:14)
    at Function.process_params (/home/srithan/Desktop/Right_doc/Tutorial/mongodb/Mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:421:3)
    at next (/home/srithan/Desktop/Right_doc/Tutorial/mongodb/Mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
```

Version of Mongdb : 5.0.18

Code snippet:

```js
app.get('/Movies/:id',(req,res)=>{

    if(ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)){
        db.collection('Movies')
            .findOne({_id: ObjectId(req.params.id)})
            .then(result=>{
                res.status(200).json(result)
            })
            .catch((err)=>{
                res.status(404).send(err)
            })
    }
    else{
        res.status(400).send("Invalid ID")
    }
})
```

Comment: What happens if you use `{_id: new ObjectId(req.params.id)}`?

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/Movies/:id',(req,res)=>{

if(ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)){
    db.collection('Movies')
        .findOne({_id: ObjectId.createFromHexString(req.params.id)})
        .then(result=>{
            res.status(200).json(result)
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            res.status(404).send(err)
        })
}
else{
    res.status(400).send("Invalid ID")
}
```

Try using ObjectId.createFromHexString() instead of ObjectId() to convert your id